# Bake single frame of ocean modifier into texture

Tags: texture-baking, baking, ocean-simulation

I am new to blender and I would like to know if it is possible to bake a single keyframe of the ocean modifier into an image.

The goal then would be to export the mesh created with the ocean modifier as a .fbx and then apply the texture to the exported mesh.

I am not sure that this is possible though.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it looks like it works, either normal baking or baking the height with a b&w gradient on the Z axis:

[image]

[image]